# Making the Label in a report equal to the value of a textbox

Tags: ms-access

So I have a form that has a button that, when clicked, will generate a report. I have a combo box in the form that will fill in a text box after it is changed. What I want to do is then take the info from that text box and display it as the header of my report using a label. I could not figure out how to do it that way, however, so I had to use a text box which works, but it is not very aesthetically pleasing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is the textbox not aesthetically pleasing? Why does it look any different from label? I have used textbox as a 'label' and looks just fine.

Comment: I was having trouble with the background of the textbox. When I ran the report it would have the background of the textbox as white, but I figured out how to edit that so it matches the background of the report. However, I can still see the black outline of the textbox. Is there any way to get rid of that? Edit: Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks for the reply.